# insert and update record

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

Hello, can anyone help me out... I have already tried a few different approaches, while trying to achieve an output like so.

```
id   idnumber    datein      timein     dateout     timeout

1     123      2013-02-21   08:00:01   2013-02-21   11:12:45

2     456      2013-02-21   10:15:01   2013-02-21   05:30:01

3     123      2013-02-21   06:58:52   2013-02-21   03:20:16

4     123      2013-02-21   10:05:35   2013-02-21
```

But then I still cant get it...I'm trying to make an attendance monitoring wherein a person can timein and timeout as many as he/she wish as long as it will be recorded to the database. I have this two codes in php that works but then not the output that i want to.

The code below is inserting a record only but update don't work:

```
if (isset($_POST['idnumber'])){
      $query = "INSERT INTO tblattendance SET idnumber='".$_POST['idnumber']."', datein=CURDATE(), timein = CURTIME()";
      $insert_result = mysql_query($query);
}else{
      $query1 = "UPDATE tblattendance SET dateout=CURDATE(), timeout = CURTIME() WHERE idnumber='".$_POST['idnumber']."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
      $insert_result1 = mysql_query($query1);   
}
```

The code below performs an insert and update only if there is no existing record of an idnumber but if the idnumber exists, it's just updating the timeout column.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblattendance WHERE idnumber='".$_POST[idnumber']."'";
$res = mysql_query($query);
list($exist) = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if (!$exist){
          $query = "INSERT INTO tblattendance SET idnumber='".$_POST['idnumber']."', datein=CURDATE(), timein = CURTIME()";
          $insert_result = mysql_query($query);
    }else{
         $query1 = "UPDATE tblattendance SET dateout=CURDATE(), timeout = CURTIME() WHERE idnumber='".$_POST['idnumber']."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
         $insert_result1 = mysql_query($query1);    
    }
```

Comment: Sorry dont understand your question. In one phrase you mentioned "The code below is inserting a record only but update don't work:" and in other you said "The code below performs an insert and update only if there is no existing record of an idnumber but if the idnumber exists, it's just updating the timeout column." ..so exactly what is the case and error ??

Comment: Don't use ORDER BY in Update-statement. And try to understand insert-statement also. The INSERT INTO .. SET x = y is only for MySQL and no standard SQL language.

Comment: beware of sql injection and also mysql_* is depricated

Comment: I just put the codes that I have tried...all of that codes doesn't really give an output that I want to. Can you give me atleast the right code for insert-update? Because I'm not really that expert when it comes to php.

Answer (score 1):

The original code was trying to insert into the database using [`UPDATE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) syntax (and not the general [`INSERT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) syntax, although it seems to be correct based on this [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)).

```
      $query = "INSERT INTO tblattendance SET idnumber='".$_POST['idnumber']."', datein=CURDATE(), timein = CURTIME()";
```

For my example I'm using a table schema  below...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblattendance` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timein` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `datein` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeout` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateout` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Removed some duplication from the original code by [rhein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841014/rhein)

```
//grab the id_number
$id_number = $_POST['idnumber'];
//fetch rows
$query = "SELECT * FROM test.tblattendance WHERE idnumber='".$id_number."'";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);
//create an initial query to update the database
$query = "UPDATE test.tblattendance SET dateout=CURDATE(), timeout = CURTIME() WHERE idnumber='".$id_number."'";
//check we have no rows
if (empty($rows)){
      //because we have no rows modify the query
      $query = "INSERT INTO test.tblattendance VALUES('', $id_number, CURDATE(), CURDATE(), null, null);";
} @mysql_query($query);
```

In order to be effective against SQL injection. All elements from `$_POST` should be wrapped with [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or you should be replacing apostrophes found in `$_POST` with ASCII characters, before querying the database.

Comment: what if I want to record again the same IDNumber with new timein and timeout?

Comment: I tried but it's just updates the timeout column. What I want is after updating the timeout column, if I post again the IDNumber it will insert to a new row with new timein?

Comment: @rhein you were using the incorrect syntax when updating the database.

Comment: I have tried your code Sir but it doesn't work for me...as you can see in my table I have an auto-incremented field and I have an IDNumber field. so id and idnumber columns are not the same.

Comment: @rhein I have modified the query in the answer to fit your `table schema` (though in the future you should learn inserts, from the link [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) I've provided on w3schools for correct syntax).

Comment: Thanks for helping. I finally got it :)